# NSImageView Drag and Drop issues

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drag-and-drop, nsimageview, nsbox

I have an NSBox containing two static text fields and two NSImageView.
    NSBox is subclassed as myNSBox. 
    I have registered the view/NSBox to accept appropriate drag types. 
    So when i drag items to the static text fields, the drag-drop operations work. 
    However, dragging and dropping onto any NSImageView (which are subviews of NSBox) does not work. 
    An interesting observation is that i am unable to drag and drop files from Finder onto the image view. Drag and Drop from outline view to the NSImageView works fine.

**Any suggestions**?

Comment: Updated the problem statement.

Answer (score 7):

Anyways, i found the solution. One has to unregisterForDragTypes the image view.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me, thank you! You should accept your answer @user598789

Comment: Thx! One is also very likely to run into this with NSTableView and -[NSTableCellView imageView].